# Topic(s) [test-topic-new] is/are not present and missingTopicsFatal is true

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am running one consumer service in a server(12.255.123.789). there are 3 kafka servers(XX.XXX.XXX.123, XX.XXX.XXX.124, XX.XXX.XXX.125) in a cluster and three zookeeper servers(YY.YYY.YYY.123, YY.YYY.YYY.124, YY.YYY.YYY.125) are running. My consumer properties are

```
spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers=XX.XXX.XXX.123:9092,XX.XXX.XXX.124:9092,XX.XXX.XXX.125:9092
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id: prod
#spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset: earliest
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset: latest
spring.kafka.consumer.key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
spring.kafka.listener.concurrency: 6
```

I have used this command to create topics in kafka server(XX.XXX.XXX.123,XX.XXX.XXX.124,XX.XXX.XXX.125)

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper YY.YYY.YYY.123:2181,YY.YYY.YYY.124:2181,YY.YYY.YYY.125:2181 --replication-factor 2 --partitions 1 --topic test-topic-new --config cleanup.policy=delete --config delete.retention.ms=60000
```

While starting my consumer service on 12.255.123.789 server I am having below exception -

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'org.springframework.kafka.config.internalKafkaListenerEndpointRegistry'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Topic(s) [test-topic-new] is/are not present and missingTopicsFatal is true
```

Am I doing anything wring here?

Comment: Check whether your Kafka topic was created using ```bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper YY.YYY.YYY.123:2181```.

Answer (score 0):

The communication between kafka servers were not established. Thats why the application was unable to find the topics. We need to set one leader node. After this application ran smoothly.

```
advertised.listners=PLAINTEXT://<serverIP:port>
```